# what esc code sends tear off in Epson fx-1170

Tags: printing, matrix

what is  esc code to to send manual TEAR OFF command in Epson ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ESC code for the Tear OFF option, when the printer receives [FF] (Form Feed control character) and the page length is set correctly, the printer will feed the page to the Tear Off position.